# Javascript: Replacing text in HTML object

Tags: javascript

I've got a HTML object `obj` and I'm attempting to replace a string in it's inner HTML with another..

```
obj.innerHTML.replace('<a>theoldstring</a><span></span>','thenewstring');
```

However, the string isn't replacing and is printing the same before and after.. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call is just returning the new string. Look in the docs how javascript's replace function works.

```
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace('<a>theoldstring</a><span></span>','thenewstring');
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace()` does not modify the original object. Instead it returns a new instance, hence an assigment is needed:

```
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace('<a>theoldstring</a><span></span>','thenewstring');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace('<a>theoldstring</a><span></span>','thenewstring');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.innerHTML = 'thenewstring';
```